# How does api archive.org works?

Tags: api

As you surely know web.archive.org lets you inspect the history of a domain, ie:http://web.archive.org/web/*/besttatoo.com

I also has an API: http://archive.org/help/json.php

I need to get data from the API but I can't get many info on how to use it, has anyone used it and can paste some examples of use?

Answer (score 2):

This link provides details about the item LovingU on archive.org:

http://archive.org/details/LovingU&output=json

To create an API query to your liking, use this page:

https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php#raw

That page allows you to choose your output format: JSON, XML, HTML, CSV or RSS and also the parameters your want to see. You can limit the number of results, too.

Comment: once you use this form to get a .json callback, what do you do with it?